# Photos unable to consolidate referenced photos

Tags: icloud, photos, filesystem, aperture

I recently imported my Aperture library of 17,000 referenced images into Photos. Initially, they were referenced in Photos as well. Since I plan to upload my entire library to iCloud Photo library I told Photos to consolidate all 17,000 files. This revealed a problem. Photos is unable to locate and consolidate about a 1000 of my photos even though Aperture has no problem pointing me to them when hitting "Show in Finder".

The weird thing is, Photos offers me to locate these files for it. I then navigate to the exact folder where the file is stored and even made sure that its filename is identical to the name of the file Photos states it cannot find in that folder. At this point I'm stuck. What can I do to make Photos identify these files correctly?

I'm happy to provide additional information if anyone tells me what might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, although I was reluctant to try it at first, what eventually solved my problem, was to

1. relocate *all* files into the Aperture library,
2. completely delete the Photos library,
3. reimport the Aperture library with all photos now managed.

Steps 1 and 2 can run in parallel to save time. After doing this, Photos is now able to scan all 17,000 photos for faces and upload all of them to my iCloud Photo library.